# How can I show a list of product options as checkboxes in the cart?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, craft3, craft-pro, plugin-craftcommerce2

In my cart (Craft3/Commerce2), I need to show a line item's possible options from a checkbox field called "productOptions", and allow the user to select the desired options.

Based on the [Craft Docs](https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-docs/blob/3728ec51450bcab22509f1a6c04ff66c58c9d4e9/en/adding-to-and-updating-the-cart.md#line-item-options-and-notes), I can manually test if an item.options exists, but this means hard-coding the list of possible options(35+) into the cart, and keeping that updated as available options change:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/update-line-item">
    {{ redirectInput('cart') }}
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="lineItemId" value="{{ item.id }}">
    <span {% if item.getFirstError('qty') %}class="has-error"{% endif %}>
    <input type="number" name="qty" min="1" value="{{ item.qty }}"></span>


{#  Manual List of Options to Test if Exists #}
    {% if item.options.optionOne is defined %}
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="options[optionOne]" checked> Option One 
        </label>
    {% endif %}
    {% if item.options.optionTwo is defined %}
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="options[optionTwo]" checked> Option Two 
        </label>
    {% endif %}
            ...
```

OR, I can output the list of product options available for a given product, and use that to update the cart:

```
{#  To access the product options, set a variable "product" #}
    {% set product = item.purchasable.product %}
    {% for key, value in product.productOptions %}

        <label class="checkbox">
{#          <input type="hidden" name="options[{{ value }}]" value=""> #}<!-- uncheck it if not checked -->
            <input type="checkbox"  name="options[{{ value }}]" value="on" 
            {% if item.options.value is defined %}checked{% endif %}> {{ value }} 
        </label>

    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to test if the checkbox is selected/value =="on" from the cart array. I know that 
`{% if item.options.value is defined %}checked{% endif %}`
is not the correct way to access this value if it even can be accessed in this for loop.

Help? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`{% if item.options.value is defined and item.options.value == 'on' %}`